# Yii2 ListView custom data-attribute based on currend DP model

Tags: php, listview, yii2, render

I need to set custom data-attribute to the ListView elements. As example I try to get current DataProvider model id. But I still view error "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given". Please check my code and halp me - how I should get this ID?

```
 <?= ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $photoProvider,
            'id' => 'photo-list',
            'itemView' => '_photoListItem',
            'viewParams' => [
                'fullView' => true,
            ],
            'options' => [
                'tag' => 'ul',
                'class' => 'list-view'
            ],
            'itemOptions' => [
                'tag' => 'li',
                'class' => 'item',
                'data' =>[
                    'test' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                        return Html::encode($model->id);
                    }
                ]
            ],
            'pager' => [
                'class' => ScrollPager::className(),
                'container' => '#photo-list',
                'item' => '.item',
                'triggerText' => '<div class="btn more">Load More</div>',
                'noneLeftText' => '',
                'triggerOffset' => 2,
                'negativeMargin' => 200
            ],
            'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
        ]);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the ListView, according to the [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#renderTagAttributes%28%29-detail):

```
'data' => [
  'test' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
    return Html::encode($model->id);
  }
]
```

You cannot use a function here. Only static values are allowed.

Alternatively, you can provide those attributes in tags of your `_photoListItem` view file.

Comment: @ДимаПолхов It starts working after trying it 3 days! ;-) No, I know, there are similar things that work this way. And IMO it would useful if these data attributes could be populated how you have tried it. You could make a feature request for this on github.